# Specifying a file location in a Unit Test with Visual Studio tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have a set of text files that I need to have a test take in and use the items for specific parts of some Unit tests I am writing.  I have put a file path in my app.config of just: .\DataLists\

After I put that in there I added the items needed to add a custom section so it would then get that file path information.  The problem I am having is this...it is not finding those lists in that location it is looking at some tmp folder instead.  How do I specify a proper file location for this?

Comment: Could you post the code? It's easier to answer this way. Feel free to remove personal information from the code if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `DeploymentItemAttribute`? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  Use this on the test method(s) where you need access to your 'set' (folder I assume) of text files.  The best practice here is to add the folder and files you want deployed to your project file and set them to 'Copy if newer' or 'Copy Always'.

You can also add the file(s) or folder to the Deployment section of the .testsettings configuration screen.  In my experience this works better during Team Builds than the `DeploymentItemAttribute` route.  In either case the 'Enable deployment' check box found in the .testsettings config screen must be checked.